# Restricting space text can take up in a div

Tags: html, css, angularjs, text, styles

I am making a program called "AngularJS whiteboard."  To put it simply, it takes text from a textbox and prints it in real time on a picture of a whiteboard, which is the background picture for the div.

I've discovered by changing the div height I can change how much of the picture is displayed.  However, I cannot seem to use the width to contain the added text so it does not go right of the whiteboard picture.  It simply keeps printing horizontally indefinitely.

Is there a  way to restrict how far the text will go horizontally, then have it break to the next line?  And, preferably, vertically too?

```css
      #whiteboard 
    {
     font-family: cursive;
     font-size: 24px;
     background-image: url('whiteboard_pic.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding: 25px;
     height: 700px;
     width: 1000px;
    }
    
    span {
     margin-left: 24px;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    
    
    <title>AngularJS Whiteboard</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
    <div ng-app="">
     
    
    
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="30" ng-model="writing">
    </textarea>
    <span>    Marker color: <input type = "text" size = "7" ng-model="marker_color"></span>
    <span>    Writing size: <input type = "text" size = "7" ng-model="writing_size"></span>
    
    <br>
    <br>
    
    <div id = "whiteboard" ng-bind="writing" ng-style="{ color : marker_color, 'font-size': writing_size + 'px'}"> 
     
    </div>
    
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have your application return the values inside of a block item container element that has specific dimensions. This will allow you to control where the outputted text breaks and when a horizontal scrollbar should be shown.

**Example:**

```css
.output {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="output">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sem lectus, tempor sit amet ullamcorper quis, sodales rutrum nibh. Cras erat leo, viverra ut velit vel, venenatis pharetra mauris. Nam ultricies ac lorem a mollis. Ut dapibus massa nunc, eu lacinia ligula elementum eu. Mauris consequat dolor diam, eget commodo eros vulputate id. Cras a sollicitudin tortor. Donec diam turpis, pharetra vestibulum porta et, venenatis ac ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin lacinia luctus suscipit. Donec in facilisis ex.</div>
```

Adjust the width and height to fit your desired dimensions. You may need to position this element relatively over your whiteboard.